# How to upgrade apache2.2.x to 2.2.x+1 on windows

Tags: windows, apache-2.2

I have apache 2.2 installed on windows 2003 on a production web server and need to upgrade it to the newest point release.

Apache only provide an installer for windows (or source .. if i want to compile) - if I install over the top of my current install will it work? Or is that going to break things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the same branch configuration files are fully compatible.

But you can test you new apache configuration with an other tcp port : read this doc to change binding :
[apache bind](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/bind.html)

1. Install new apache in other directory
2. Change binding configuration in you new apache
3. Change your configuration to set modules, files & logs directory etc...
4. Configtest and Start you new apache and check you site with your new apache

Comment: nice idea, i like it. not the one click answer i was hoping to find - but looks like there isn't a risk free one click upgrade, so accepting this.